# Read less info of apk file with aapt tool

Tags: android, windows, aapt

I'm using aapt tool to read content of apk file with:

```
aapt d badging myapk.apk
```

But the output is too much. I just need the package name and version name. Any way to limit it?

**Update:** I got it to work on window cmd. Look like this:

```
aapt d badging myapk.apk | find "pack"
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

//try this

```
aapt d badging myapk.apk | grep 'pack'
```

its showing for me as

```
padmakumar@padmakumar-desktop:~$ aapt d badging ./Desktop/NhpAndroid_tablet_k4.apk  | grep 'pack'
package: name='com.ti.et.nspire.android' versionCode='1' versionName='1.0'
```

Comment: hmmm... is it for linux? how can i get the same with cmd in window 7?

Comment: nice answer, what if I want to show `package: name='com.**',  versionCode='xx',  versionName='xx.xx', ((sdkVersion:'xx', lable:'xxxx'))`?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a trick that work like charm for me. 
I'm using Backtrack 5 r2 ; GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)

Assuming that "./aapt" executable is on the same directory of the Shell or Script. If not just add the path to executable or use export aapt="/path/to/aapt" and use the variable path.

**out=$(./aapt dump badging GameCIH.apk | grep 'application-label:' | awk -F: 'match($0,":"){ print substr($0,RSTART+1)}' | tr -d "'" )**

From **aplication-label:'GameCIH'** on apk

To only:

**GameCIH**

One last thing. If you want the package name or version name then do this:

**out=$(./aapt dump badging GameCIH.apk | grep 'versionName=' | awk -F: 'match($0,"versionName="){ print substr($2,RSTART-8)}' | tr -d "'" )**

This will return for example:

**versionName=3.0.0**

Just change the values **versionName** to whatever you need.

Change **RSTART-8** for something like this: **RSTART+4** and that will return:

**3.0.0**

I hope this could help!

Answer (score 2):

```
aapt d badging myapk.apk | grep package
```

for Windows, download UnxUtils to get grep and much more Linux command:
    http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/UnxUtils.zip

Answer (score 1):

```
aapt d badging myapk.apk | awk '/package/ {print($2)}' | awk '{print(mstr[split($1, mstr, \"=\")])}' | tr -d \"'\"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Bash function:

```
# Display package name and version of APK file(s)
apk(){
    (
        set -o pipefail

        for path in "$@"; do
            aapt dump badging "$path" \
            | awk $'
                BEGIN {
                    p=""
                    v=""
                }

                match($0, /^package: name=\'([^\']*)\'/, a) {
                    p=a[1]
                }

                match($0, /versionName=\'([^\']*)\'/, b) {
                    v=b[1]
                }

                END {
                    if (length(p) && length(v)) {
                        print p, v
                    }
                }'
        done
    )
}
```